# Why can't i output outside a function, in this scenario where i'm creating a simple counter i'm confused as to why it's working inside and not out?

Tags: javascript, function, counter

Why can't I output outside the function here, why does it need to be inside?

```
counter = 0;

function countJar() {
  counter += 1
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = counter;
}
// why can't it be here?
```

Comment: you can, counter is global it's attached to window

Comment: Do you mean that when you put the `innerHTML` assignment at the end you don't even see `0` in the output? If so, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: yes, this exactly. however, just not in jquery. I'm still on the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if it were where you've shown in the question, the value would be `0`. The code runs immediately on page load, it doesn't wait for something to call `countJar`. Where it is now, it doesn't run until `countJar` is called.

**If** you mean you can't even see `0` when you try to put it there, that would be because the `id="demo"` element doesn't exist yet. If that's what you mean, [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) apply.